# mmenu.debugger.js error: Missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

When I build my js files via Apache Ant Library (The commands I use are "ant clean all" or "ant build"), I'm getting syntax error in mmenu.debugger.js library file.

The code scope which has the error:

```
[
  'setPage',
  'openPanel',
  'closePanel',
  'closeAllPanels',
  'setSelected'
].forEach(method => {
            this.bind(method + ':before', method => {
                if (typeof panel != 'undefined' && panel instanceof jQuery) {
                    deprecated(
                        'Passing a jQuery object as an argument to the "' +
                            method +
                            '" API method',
                        'a HTMLElement',
                        '8.0.0'
                    );
                }
            });
        });
```

```
if (typeof panel != 'undefined' && panel instanceof jQuery) {
```

Missing ; before statement error in this if line

note: deprecated() is a function in this file.